# How do I make the Eclipse Ant builder use the compiler built into Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I have an eclipse project which uses an ant script to do some additional build steps, such as building jars.

When someone first imports the project, the ant build fails because it can't find javac in the classpath. Adding the path to the JDK to JAVA_HOME makes the build work, but I'd rather not have this requirement, and instead just build using the built-in compiler in eclipse.

Is there a simple way to configure the project/ant builder to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set the ant target to use eclipse compiler... looks pretty complicated, but here you go

http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/index.cgi/jdt-core-home/howto/batch%20compile/batchCompile.html?revision=1.4